# Fullpage.js not at the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, fullpage.js

I am having a problem with fullscreen js.

The problem is that the fullpage is not at the top of the screen:

[image]

This is my HTML(Im using Django):

```
    {% extends 'layout/app.html' %}


    <body>
        {% block content %}
        <div id="fullpage">
                <div class="section" id="section1">Some section</div>
                <div class="section">Some section</div>
                <div class="section">Some section</div>
                <div class="section">Some section</div>
            </div>

        {% endblock %}
    </body>
```

The `base.html` where `index.html` extends from:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Portfolio/css/normalize/normalize.css' %}" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Portfolio/css/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Portfolio/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Portfolio/css/style.css' %}" />
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    {% block navbar %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <script src="{% static 'Portfolio/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'Portfolio/js/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                //sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
                anchors: ['Welcome', 'Portfolio', 'Skills', 'About', 'Contact'],


    menu: '#menu',
            scrollingSpeed: 1000
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#section1 {
    background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I have tried setting `margin : 0` i also have normalize.css linked.

So there is no margin or padding applied to the fullpage and to the body. What can cause this issue?

EDIT:

The navbar is empty and i tried removing it app.html, it didnt work.

EDIT:

Putting everything in one html files fixes the problem. This means is probably has something to do with django's templating engine. But what can it be?

Comment: you nav bar, is it empty !?

Comment: What I would recommend is using the mouse to select the element on the rendered page by (1) opening chrome dev tools with the `f12` key. (2) select the element selector tool by hitting `Ctrl + Shift + C` simultaneously.  (3) hover over the white space at the top, and click. (4) add a screen shot of that to your question.  That would be a huge help.

Comment: @M0ns1f yes it is

Comment: @JaeGeeTee I did that the fullpage is not part of the bar but the body is, the fullpage just doesnt get places at the top for some reason.

Comment: i think that white space is the nav bar,try giving the nav class transparent backgroun-color;

Comment: @M0ns1f i tried removing the navbar from app.html as well and it doesnt work. Making the body transparent also didnt work.

Comment: I think that I have seen some weirdness with line-height.  I'm reallllly stretching here (beware).  Try setting the line-height on body to 0 or 0px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem,
There was a no break space
charachter added to the body, changing the encoding to ANSII worked.